# can we have a Taylor series expansion of the function $\frac{1}{\zeta(s)}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series, zeta-functions, dirichlet-series, analytic-continuation

can we have a Taylor series expansion of the function $\frac{1}{\zeta(s)}$at $s=1$?
if so how can we determine the radius of convergence of this expansion without assuming the truth of the riemann hypothesis?

Comment: Properties of [Stieltjes constants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stieltjes_constants) may [help](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=series%281%2Fzeta%281%2Bx%29%2Cx%29) (but perhaps not much...)

Comment: Did you mean T**a**ylor series?

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Series%5B1%2FZeta%5Bs%5D%2C%7Bs%2C1%2C5%7D%5D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The zeros of $\zeta(s)$ are the poles of $1/\zeta(s)$. From the functional equation, we know $s=-2$ is a trivial zero and from computer calculations $\zeta(s)$ has no nontrivial zeros in $|\Im(s)|\le10$, so we conclude that the radius of convergence for the Taylor expansion of $1/\zeta(s)$ is $|(-2)-1|=3$.

Comment: Thank you bro..

Comment: I was wondering if there is another way to check like the ratio test for power series or something like that?

Comment: @Haidara checking poles is much more easier than only looking at the coefficients